# Proof of ${ \prod_{i=0}^{n}{x_i} < \overline{x}^{n} }$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, algorithms

**Problem Definition:**

I was studying randomized algorithms and the following appeared:

${ 1- \prod_{i=0}^{N}{(1- {y_i})} \ge  \beta_k {z_j} }$

We also know that ${ {y_i} + ... + {y_k} \ge {z_j} }$

And ${ {y_i},{z_j} \in [0,1] }$

And the following was written: "The expression on the left is minimized when ${ {y_i} = {z_j}/k}$"

by minimizing, it means:
${ 1- \prod_{i=0}^{N}{(1- {y_i})} \ge  1- \prod_{i=0}^{N}{(1- {{z_j}/k})}  }$

(Randomized Algorithms, Montwani && Raghavn; page 106, 107).

---

**My reasoning, first try:**

So, I figure that to minimize

${ 1- \prod_{i=0}^{N}{(1- {y_i})} }$

you need to minimize

${{y_i}}$

Now, At the very least:
${ {y_i} + ... + {y_k} \ge {z_j} }$ 
meaning, ${z_j/k}$  is the minimum average possible of all the y.

${z_j/k}$ can't then be always smaller than ${y_i}$.

Ok, so that didn't work...

---

So, It seems to me that the only way possible out of this is if:

${ \prod_{i=0}^{n}{x_i} <  \overline{x}^{ n} }$

holds as a general property and

if ${x_i}$ in this example would be ${1-y_i}$

---

My apologies if anything is wrongly explained or out of what's normal around mathematicians and this website, I'm fairly modest at math!

Thanks for your help!

I've search quite a bit, but I don't seem to find a proof about it or any mention. It's also hard to google math.

Can you help me?

Comment: [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic mean (AM):
$$
{\displaystyle {\bar {x}_a}={\frac {1}{n}}\left(\sum _{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}}\right)}
$$
Geometric mean (GM):
$$
\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle {\bar {x}_g}=\left(\prod _{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}}\right)^{\frac {1}{n}}}\\
\end{equation}
$$

Since 
$$
{\displaystyle \mathrm {AM} \geq \mathrm {GM}}
$$
We have
$$
{\displaystyle {\bar {x}_a} \ge \left(\prod _{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}}\right)^{\frac {1}{n}}}\\
{\displaystyle {\bar {x}_a}^n \ge \left(\prod _{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}}\right)}
$$
See [Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean)